# Dynamic Programming Simple Example at C?

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I need some examples about Dynamic Programming at Language C.
I am study algorithm with C now but at this book, examples are too hard to understand.
Does anyone give me some example for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recursive function:- without dynamic programming it will call the same function multiple times.

```
 int nCr(int n,int r){
     if (r == 0 || r == n || n == 1 || n == 0){
        return 1;
 }
 else{
    return nCr(n-1,r) + nCr(n-1,r-1);
 }
}
```

Now with the help of Dynamic Programming:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int n,r;
    scanf("%d%d",&n,&r);

    int mem[n+1][r+1];

    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<n+1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<r+1;j++)
        {
            if (j == 0 || j == i || i == 1 || i == 0)
                mem[i][j]=1;
            else
                mem[i][j]=mem[i-1][j]+mem[i-1][j-1];
        }
    }

    printf("%d",mem[n][r]);


    return 0;
}
```

I have used a 2D-array to save values so that i can use them instead of calling the function again and again. I have used Dynamic Programming concept.

Comment: you can upvote the answer if you understood it.